# List to csv without commas in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a following problem.
I would like to save a list into a csv (in the first column).
See example here:

```
import csv

mylist = ["Hallo", "der Pixer", "Glas", "Telefon", "Der Kühlschrank brach kaputt."]


def list_na_csv(file, mylist):

    with open(file, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        csv_writer.writerows(mylist)


list_na_csv("example.csv", mylist)
```

My output in excel looks like this:
[image]

Desired output is:
[image]

You can see that I have two issues: Firstly, each character is followed by comma. Secondly, I don`t know how to use some encoding, for example UTF-8 or cp1250. How can I fix it please?

I tried to search similar question, but nothing worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Try writerow instead of writerows

Comment: Are you looking for `csv_writer.writerow(mylist)`?

Comment: Is this the structure used for your real data (one string per row), or just a simplified example? If it is your real data - how does what you're trying to do differ from just writing the contents of the list to a file without specifically making it a CSV file? With one element per row there's nothing to separate. Assuming you're not in fact trying to just write the list to a single row, in which case the `writerow()` suggestion will fix your main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1. `writerows` expects a list of rows, said differently a list of iterables. As a string is iterable, you write each word in a different row, one character per field. If you want one row with one word per field, you should use `writerow`

   ```
    csv_writer.writerow(mylist)
   ```
2. by default, the csv module uses the comma as the delimiter (this is the most common one). But Excel is a pain in the ass with it: it expects the delimiter to be the one of the locale, which is the semicolon (`;`) in many West European countries, including Germany. If you want to use easily your file with *your* Excel you should change the delimiter:

   ```
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
   ```

---

After your edit, you want all the data in the first column, one element per row. This is kind of a decayed csv file, because it only has one value per record and no separator. If the fields can never contain a semicolon nor a new line, you could just write a plain text file:

```
...
with open(file, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    for row in mylist:
        print(row, file=file)
...
```

If you want to be safe and prevent future problems if you later want to process more *corner cases* values, you could still use the csv module and write one element per row by including it in another iterable:

```
...
with open(file, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writerows([elt] for elt in mylist)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in your case are elements from mylist in the first row. This is not the desired output. I need to have my elements in the first column. Please see my edited question above

Comment: I think in the latter case I'd still specify the delimiter because that interacts with the escaping logic - values containing the delimiter get quoted, at least in the default dialect. So if the input were `["foo, bar", "foo; bar"]` it'd make a difference whether the delimiter is `,` or `;` even though there's only one entry per row.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Of course you are right! Post edited...

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["Hallo", "der Pixer", "Glas", "Telefon", "Der Kühlschrank brach kaputt."]

with open("file.csv", "w") as msg:
    msg.write(",".join(l))
```

For less trivial examples:

```
l = ["Hallo", "der, Pixer", "Glas", "Telefon", "Der Kühlschrank, brach kaputt."]

with open("file.csv", "w") as msg:
    msg.write(",".join([ '"'+x+'"' for x in l]))
```

Here you basically set every list element between quotes, to prevent from the intra field comma problem.

Comment: Beware, the csv module is much smarter that a mere join. It does support newlines or delimiters in a field while your answer will not.

Comment: This will work on this trivial example but is a recipe for problems on real data. `l = ["foo, bar"]` will demonstrate one of the difficulties.

Comment: I have added some support for the comma problem. To my opinion, when one can make without those csv modules he should. For most they are a black box, we do not necessarily need that for smth as simple as csv.

Comment: It is a much better idea to use standard library components that cover the various non-obvious special cases than to try to solve them yourself.

Comment: @Synthase: I would agree with you for languages that do not support CSV out of the box. But Python comes *batteries included* and has a nice CSV support in its standard library. And I really hate trying to invent a more or less oval wheel, when a nice round one is available at no cost...

Comment: It depends how much you know about what you're processing. If you do process something you made, then you know how to using your own routines with more control. If you have no idea about the content you process, I acknowledge using a lib may be better. @SergeBallesta I agree. The fundamental problem with libs is that you have no idea what it is doing excepted if you get into the source code, which may be time consuming. That's my own preference, but for such simple things I prefer to know what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in your case are elements from mylist in the first cell searated by comma. This is not the desired output. Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the entire list of strings to a single row, use `csv_writer.writerow(mylist)` as mentioned in the comments.

If you want to write each string to a new row, as I believe your reference to writing them in the first column implies, you'll have to format your data as the class expects: "A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects". On this data that would look something like:

```
csv_writer.writerows((entry,) for entry in mylist)
```

There, I'm using a generator expression to wrap each word in a tuple, thus making it an iterable of strings. Without something like that, your strings are themselves iterables and lead to it delimiting between each character as you've seen.

Using csv to write a single entry per line is *almost* pointless, but it does have the advantage that it will escape your delimiter if it appears in the data.

To specify an encoding, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) say:

> Since open() is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by
> default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see
> locale.getpreferredencoding()). To decode a file using a different
> encoding, use the encoding argument of open:
>
> ```
> import csv with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>     reader = csv.reader(f)
>     for row in reader:
>         print(row)
> ```
>
> The same applies to writing in something other than the system default encoding: specify the encoding argument when
> opening the output file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution `csv_writer.writerows(tuple(entry) for entry in mylist)` gives me the same result. Each character is separated by comma. For example d,e,r, ,P,i,x,e,r etc.

Comment: Oh, of course, `tuple` on an iterable converts the iterable to a tuple of its elements, not a tuple of just the iterable. `writerows((entry,) for entry in mylist)` would work - that's basically doing the same thing as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work 100%

```
import csv
mylist = ["Hallo", "der Pixer", "Glas", "Telefon", "Der Kühlschrank brach kaputt."]
def list_na_csv(file, mylist):
    with open(file, "w") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(mylist)
list_na_csv("example.csv", mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in your case are elements from mylist in the first cell searated by comma. This is not the desired output. Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

try split("\n")
example:

```
counter = 0
amazing list = ["hello","hi"]
for x in titles:
        ok = amazinglist[counter].split("\n")
        writer.writerow(ok)
        counter +=1
```